# Mocha chai resolve multiple promises

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, tdd, chai

I'm trying to run the tests on this promises but I get this error:

"Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure" done () "is called; if returning to Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\Users\Ranieri\Documents\Projetos\Node Js\testestest\test\libs\registerUser.test.js)"

I have already increased the timeout time but it still does not solve the problem.

I searched for asynchronous test here on stackoverflow and found nothing or anyone with something similar

my test code https://github.com/ran-j/teste

Already tried :

`expect(Promise.resolve( userPromesie.selectUser(rUser)  ) ).to.be.null`

`return expect(Promise.resolve( userPromesie.selectUser(rUser)  ) ).to.be.null`

`userPromesie.selectUser(rUser).then((result) => result.to.be.null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectUser` returns a `Promise` and you need to wait for this to resolve in order to be able to assert against it. This can achieved two ways:

- Using `then` on the returning promise, calling the `done()` function within that block.
- Using `async/await`, you declare your function `async` and you `await` the Promise

Below is an example of an `async/await` method:

```
it('should do something with the user', async () => {
    const user = await userPromise.selectUser(rUser);
    expect(user).to.be.null;
});
```

I'd highly recommend reading up on Promises for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

**EDIT** Here's an example using the done method:

```
it('should do something with the user', (done) => {
    userPromise.selectUser(rUser).then((user) => {
        expect(user).to.be.null;
        done();
    });

});
```

Comment: Same error..., I kwon how promesis works and I try with then, finally ....

Comment: I've added an example using the `done` method. Hopefully that works for you!